# zip and download Django Rest Framework generated json file

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Let's suppose that my django rest framework app is returning this json for this url (where 4 is the pk of a model): `http:mydomain.com/model_number/4/?format=json`

```
[
    {
        "id": 96, 
        "title": "title 1",
        "picture": "static/uploads/pic1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 97, 
        "title": "title 2",
        "picture": "static/uploads/pic2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 98, 
        "title": "title 3",
        "picture": "static/uploads/pic3.jpg"
    }
]
```

I want to create and download a zip with a json file which has the content explained above (generated by django rest framework), and a folder with `pic1`, `pic2` and `pic3`.

I'm able to download a zip with a folder containing those pictures, but I don't know how to include the json file.

I don't know if it is related with [parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers#jsonparser):

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just construct an instance of your serializer with model instance as argument. Serializer object has property `data`.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...

class YourModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

your_json = YourModelSerializer(YourModel.objects.get(pk=5)).data
```

You also can use queryset with flag `many=True`:

```
your_json = YourModelSerializer(YourModel.objects.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it was really helpfull